# What's the sense of 'so' in "for Oz so ordered it"

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

> "Because if you did not wear spectacles the brightness and glory of the Emerald City would blind you. Even those who live in the City must wear spectacles night and day. They are all locked on, **for Oz so ordered it** when the City was first built, and I have the only key that will unlock them."
>
> He opened the big box, and Dorothy saw that it was filled with spectacles of every size and shape. All of them  had green glass in them. ... ...
>
> <sub>The Wonderful Wizard of Oz</sub>

I don't quite understand the use of 'so' in "for Oz so ordered it". Any thoughts?

Comment: for ... so ... is interchangeable with 'because'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means "Oz ordered it to be so", or "Oz ordered it to be that way", that is, he ordered that the spectacles be locked on.
A like phrase occurs in legal documents after a description of the decision of a court: "So ordered...".

Comment: Can we say: "Oz ordered it so"?

Comment: Yes, though it would sound archaic. Try searching for "ordered it so" at Google books.